Yolov5 transfer learning - runs/train/exp and runs/val/exp problem
I did transfer learning with yolov5 and obtained weights and everything. The val_labels are marked with bounding box crtly but val_pred doesnt have a bounding box at all . nothing is present in val_pred.same with train_pred . My yaml file only contains 1 class person.I tried with 2 classes aswell.But somehow labeling is correct but no prediction happens .
The data is annotated perfectly . (I tried bounding box to check the annotation ) . But it works on another dataset which contains 2 classes so i am not sure y this is happening .
I tried out for 1 class - 'person' (in yaml file 'names') .So I was expecting the val_pred to have class name and pred as it did when i used 2 classes(for another dataset) .The precision recall diagrams are also showing how bad the prediction is .
I am using vscode
The prediction looks like
val_batch0_pred
python yolov5/train.py --weights yolov5s.pt --data transfer_upside.yaml --img 640 --half
The labels look like
val_batch0_labels
python yolov5/val.py --weights yolov5/runs/train/exp19/weights/best.pt --data transfer_upside.yaml --img 640 --half
